# java slot machine code OOP VS procedural

Tags: java

Hey guys so I wrote this code to see how long till marge runs out of coins in slotmachine only text. So way it works the procedural ver. ( works flawless)
She plays machine 1 2 3 in just that order one , two , three.

I wrote OOP code for same thing but for some reason the coin var or bucket in this case keeps going far to negative aka 0 -1 -2. I put in simple code to stop at 0 but it goes to -2.

Here is code that works.

```
public class Coins {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runSlots(5000, 30, 10, 9);
    }

    public static void runSlots(int totalCoins, int firstStep, int secondStep, int thirdStep) {
        int coins = totalCoins;
        int timePlayed = 0;
        int machineOneStep = firstStep, machineTwoStep = secondStep, machineThreeStep = thirdStep;
        System.out.println("How many quarters does Marge have in the jar? " + totalCoins);
        System.out.println("How many times has the first machine been played since paying a jackpot?" + machineOneStep);
        System.out.println("How many times has the second machine been played since paying a jackpot?" + machineTwoStep);
        System.out.println("How many times has the third machine been played since paying a jackpot?" + machineThreeStep);

        while (coins != 0) { //machine one
            coins -= 1;
            machineOneStep += 1;
            timePlayed += 1;
            //machine two
            coins -= 1;
            machineTwoStep += 1;
            timePlayed += 1;
            //machine three
            coins -= 1;
            timePlayed += 1;
            machineThreeStep += 1;
            if (machineOneStep == 40) {
                machineOneStep = 1;
                coins += 30;
            }
            if (machineTwoStep == 85) {
                machineTwoStep = 1;
                coins += 60;
            }
            if (machineThreeStep == 10) {
                machineThreeStep = 1;
                coins += 11;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Marge played " + timePlayed + " times, but has run out of money.");
    }
}
```

And here is the OOP code

```
public class SlotMachine {

    private int machineNumber, payout, currentStep, winningStep;

    public SlotMachine(int mN, int pO, int s, int wS) {
        this.machineNumber = mN;
        this.payout = pO;
        this.currentStep = s;
        this.winningStep = wS;
    }

    public int getWinningStep() {
        return this.winningStep;
    }
    public void setWinningStep(int winningStep) {
        this.winningStep = winningStep;
    }

    public int getMachineNumber() {
        return this.machineNumber;
    }
    public void setMachineNumber(int machineNumber) {
        this.machineNumber = machineNumber;
    }

    public int getPayout() {
        return this.payout;
    }
    public void setPayout(int payout) {
        this.payout = payout;
    }

    public int getCurrentStep() {
        return this.currentStep;
    }
    public void setCurrentStep(int currentStep) {
        this.currentStep = currentStep;
    }

    public int play() {
        boolean isWinner = false;
        int amountWon = -1;
        this.currentStep = getCurrentStep() + 1;
        if (getCurrentStep() == getWinningStep()) {
            isWinner = true;
            setCurrentStep(1);
            amountWon = getPayout();
            return amountWon;
        } else
            return amountWon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + "Slot machine number " + machineNumber + " payout is " + payout + " and  currentStep is " + currentStep;
    }
}
```

and the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bucket = 5000;
    int timePlayed = 0;
    SlotMachine slotOne = new SlotMachine(1, 30, 17, 40);
    SlotMachine slotTwo = new SlotMachine(2, 60, 72, 85);
    SlotMachine slotThree = new SlotMachine(3, 11, 6, 10);
    System.out.println("How many quarters does Martha have in the bucket? " + bucket);
    while (bucket != 0) {

        //bucket-=1;
        bucket += slotOne.play();
        timePlayed += 1;
        System.out.println(bucket);
        //bucket-=1;
        bucket += slotTwo.play();
        timePlayed += 1;
        System.out.println(bucket);
        //bucket-=1;
        bucket += slotThree.play();
        timePlayed += 1;
        System.out.println(bucket);
        //failsafe
        if (bucket <= 0) {
            bucket = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Margerie plays " + timePlayed + " times.");
}
```

Comment: If you want some one to read you code I suggest you fix the formatting for a start.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: First off, please fix the formatting -- make each class into it's own code block with the proper indenting. Second, I suspect the reason you are getting different results is due to the current step being different between the two implementations. The first one is 30/10/9 while the second is 17/72/6.

Comment: Ill just put in pastebin so it looks better sorry. http://pastebin.com/F5REf2cP is this better?

Comment: You don't need pastebin to make it look better, code blocks (you can toggle them via the `{}` symbol with selected text) can be separated by putting some regular text in between. And when removing all the blank lines, your code gets readable.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not testing on every event of "coins -= 1", you are in a while, and you subtract three times before it tests if the coin is 0.

For example: 
if your event of coin begins at value 1, you will subtract it three times resulting on number -2 and never stoping, depending on the steps you input.

try this:

```
    public static void runSlots(int totalCoins,int firstStep,int secondStep, int thirdStep){
         int coins = totalCoins;
         int timePlayed = 0;
         int machineOneStep = firstStep ,machineTwoStep = secondStep , machineThreeStep = thirdStep;
            System.out.println("How many quarters does Marge have in the jar? " + totalCoins);
            System.out.println("How many times has the first machine been played since paying a jackpot?" + machineOneStep);
            System.out.println("How many times has the second machine been played since paying a jackpot?" + machineTwoStep);
            System.out.println("How many times has the third machine been played since paying a jackpot?" + machineThreeStep);

        while (coins !=0)
        {   
                //machine one
                coins -= 1;
                machineOneStep += 1;
                timePlayed +=1;
                if (machineOneStep == 40){
                    machineOneStep = 1;
                    coins += 30;
                }
                //machine two
                if (coins !=0) {
                   coins -= 1;
                   machineTwoStep += 1;
                   timePlayed +=1;
                   if (machineTwoStep == 85){
                      machineTwoStep = 1;
                      coins += 60;
                   }
                }
                //machine three
                if (coins !=0) {
                   coins -= 1;
                   timePlayed +=1;
                   machineThreeStep += 1;
                   if (machineThreeStep == 10){
                      machineThreeStep = 1;
                      coins += 11;
                   }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: machines cost 1 coin each how so its got take it 3 times. That function works anyway. Its the class I made that does not work.

Comment: If i add statement that says if coin = 0 then break ? would that make it work.

Comment: I am fixing up my code the code that does it all in one class has less playtime but for some reason the class has more played.

Comment: Actually, both classes are wrong. Just try to interpret your software. Is this really possible for me with 1 coin to play in three machines ?

Both your classes can have a negative number for coin, and that is not possible on real life.

Comment: The difference is that your inputs on the first one are satisfying your logic, but it does not mean it is right. Try inputing the first, second and third steps the same way on the Second code. you will get the same result.

Comment: I know their are exactly the same step started on 3,10, and 9. Win on same steps. 135 vs 208 (with 50 coins instead of 5000).

Comment: Think I have zeroed on it , the 3rd Machine is awarding one more on new oop one. step 3 wins 11 coins , 1st one is 58 but new one is 59 that is pushing it off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I figured it out in SlotMachine class when user wins I do not charge them so therefore I had to take won - 1; in winning part of code. Its solved.